# Redirect IP:Port to Domain Name

Tags: nginx, configuration, ubuntu-16.04

I have an IP address with port no as 45.45.45.45:8069, I am trying to redirect this to domain name example.com, currently, the website is accessible through IP address. I have used the following code but it is not working:

```
server { 
   listen 80;
   server_name 45.45.45.45:8069 ;
   return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
 }
```

I am using the following configuration:
Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx

Comment: To listen on a specific port, use: `listen 8069;`

Comment: I have already tried it didn't work. I tried following code. `server { 
   listen 8069;
   server_name 45.45.45.45 ;
   return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
 }`